# How Can I Reset up Select2 Dropdown On Click Of Button?

Tags: button, dropdown, jquery-select2, reset

I basically want to reset select2 field data not remove on click of reset button.

```
$(document).on("click",".reset",function(){
    $("#MyId").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset select2 field data:

```
$("#MyId").val('').trigger('change')
```

or

```
$("#MyId").empty().trigger('change')
```